# Encrypting foreign keys from database prior to sending to browser

Tags: asp.net, encryption, datagrid, foreign-keys, pipeline

I just came across some code that seems to encrypt database keys prior to sending them to the client (WebBrowser, Silverlight, etc).

To illustrate, suppose you have a list of students to extra-curricular activities, and a relationship defined between them.  Every time the data is written out to the ASPX page, the studentID and activityID is encrypted.  Every time a write, or modify is made, this value is sent back to the server, decrypted, and saved to the database.

What could be the reasons to expose data this way?  Is this a normal practice?

If this selective encryption is a good practice, what are the best ways of approaching it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good practice to cut down on people who just want to poke around on your site for security holes.  I mean if your student id's are sequential numbers and people are able to see the id for their page in the query string it is pretty easy to just increase the number to see if you can access the next item on the list, or build a script to iterate through all of the numbers.

Ideally you would want some security to prevent people from getting to those pages anyway if you don't want them to have access.  But even if the information was all public it could prevent people from writing a script to iterate through all of the information.

We actually do this in our product because even though we have security for data items it is up to the administrators of the site to make sure that the security is applied properly so we encrypt and decrypt keys that are exposed in the url to make it a bit safer in case the administrators don't know what they are doing and leave things open that should be locked down.

I like this extension method for easy encrypt/decrypt:
http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=69

You will need to make sure to url encode the encrypted values because they are not always url friendly when they are generated.  You can also expect to have some ugly urls like a 5 character key will encrypt to around 14 characters of random looking stuff.